# Check whether a date given in the database has been exceeded in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables with similar columns. First table is `upcoming_movies` and second is `released_movies`. There is a column `release_date` in table `upcoming_movies`. Suppose the `release_date` column has an entry `15/11/2015`, and if the given date has been exceeded then, the details in `upcoming_movies` table should move to `released_movies` table.
How I should validate the date and transfer all the details from first table to the second. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for a pure mysql solution or php aswell? also are your storing your date as 15/11/2015 or as timestamp?

Comment: Just have one table, with a flag. And store dates as dates.

Comment: Create a MySQL Event which is scheduled to run everyday. This script should automatically check to see if today date = release_date@upcoming_movies AND if it is it will then Insert it into released_movies and delete it from upcoming movies. Or whatever logic you like.. 

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html

Comment: I am storing my date as 15/11/2015 itself.

Comment: So, is the below way of coding correct ?

$d=$row['release_date'];

if($d==date('d/m/Y')){
//insert into released_movies..... 
//delete from upcoming_movies
}
else
{
//display details of upcoming_movies
}

Comment: @Noob: And also, how can i move the upcoming_movies_pics to released_movies_pics as the upcoming_movies_pics are uploaded in the upcoming_movies folder and released_movies_pics are uploaded in the released_movies folder.